# DevDemon Forms Country field is wrong

Tags: forms, devdemon, devdemon-forms

Running ExpressioneEngine 2.9.2 and DevDemon Forms 3.4.12. Whenever someone submits an entry, instead of giving me the country associated with them, I get this..

**Country: V=SPF1 A -ALL**

Any thoughts on what went wrong?

Template Code:

```
{exp:forms:form
    form_name="quick_request"
    attr:class="mfp-hide white-popup-block"
    attr:id="quickrequest"
}
```

Code rendered:

```
<form id="quickrequest" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block" method="post" action="http://previewradar.com/index/"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class='hiddenFields'>
        <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="58" />
        <input type="hidden" name="FDATA" value="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" />
        <input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="af94139e9325ef385d8d17c725aac493a3923185" />
    </div>

    <div class="dform">
        <div class="dform_element dform_name dftop_label dform_required" id="forms_field_41" style="">
            <label class="dform_label" for="ddform_41">Name <span class="req">*</span></label>
            <div class="dform_container">
                <div class="dfinput_names">
                    <div class="dfinput_left name_first">
                        <input type="text" name="fields[41][first_name]" value="" class="text  required validate[required] " id="ddform_41_first"  />
                        <label for="ddform_41_first">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dfinput_left name_last">
                        <input type="text" name="fields[41][last_name]" value="" class="text  required validate[required] " id="ddform_41_last"  />
                        <label for="ddform_41_last">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <br clear="all">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dform_element dform_text_input dftop_label dform_required" id="forms_field_42" style="">
            <label class="dform_label" for="ddform_42">Company <span class="req">*</span></label>
            <div class="dform_container">
                <input type="text" name="fields[42]" value="" class="text required validate[required] " id="ddform_42" required="required" placeholder="" data-placeholder="" maxlength=""  />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dform_element dform_email dftop_label dform_required" id="forms_field_43" style="">
            <label class="dform_label" for="ddform_43">Email <span class="req">*</span></label>
            <div class="dform_container">
                <input type="email" name="fields[43]" value="" class="text  required validate[required,custom[email]] " id="ddform_43" placeholder="" data-placeholder=""  />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dform_element dform_phone dftop_label dform_required" id="forms_field_44" style="">
            <label class="dform_label" for="ddform_44">Phone <span class="req">*</span></label>
            <div class="dform_container">
                <div class="dfinput_phones">
                    <div class="dfinput_left phone_area">
                        <input type="tel" name="fields[44][area]" value="" class="text required validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]] " id="ddform_44_area"  />
                        <label for="ddform_44_area">Area Code</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dfinput_left phone_number">
                        <input type="tel" name="fields[44][phone_number]" value="" class="text required validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]] " id="ddform_44_number"  />
                        <label for="ddform_44_number">Phone Number</label>
                    </div>
                    <br clear="all">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dform_element dform_textarea dftop_label " id="forms_field_45" style="">
            <label class="dform_label" for="ddform_45">How may we help you?</label>    
            <div class="dform_container">
                <textarea name="fields[45]" cols="50" rows="4" class="" id="ddform_45" placeholder="" data-placeholder="" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dform_element submit_button">
            <div class="dform_container">
                <div class="dfinput_full">
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit_button" value="Save" data-value="Save" data-wait="Verifying..."/>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Post your rendered form code.

Comment: posted it above.